# How to compare input value with mysql database value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

So I want to compare the input value with my database value. IF the input value is the same value as the database, I want to  `print(inputvalue)`. But if it's not the same, I want to `print("Data Does Not Exist")`

So I've tried this code :

```
cur = connection.cursor()
query = """ SELECT * FROM `foo` """

cur.execute(query)
result = cur.fetchall()
inputvalue = input("Input= ")

for x in result:
    if inputvalue not in x:
        print("Data Does Not Exist")
    else:
        print(inputvalue)
```

and this is the output:

```
inputvalue= 1728192
Data Does Not Exist
Data Does Not Exist
Data Does Not Exist
Data Does Not Exist
1728192
Data Does Not Exist
Data Does Not Exist
Data Does Not Exist
```

I expect the output is

```
Inputvalue= 1728192
Data Does Not Exist
```

**If the Data Does Not Exist**,
And this output:

```
Inputvalue= 1728192
1728192
```

**If the Data Exist**
Any answer would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make boolean object and after executing compare your answer :

```
cur = connection.cursor()
query = """ SELECT * FROM `foo` """

cur.execute(query)
result = cur.fetchall()
inputvalue = input("Input= ")

temp = False
for x in result:
    if inputvalue in x:
        temp = True
if temp:
    print(inputvalue)
else:
    print("Data Does Not Exist")
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of loading all the rows from foo into python, I would suggest to query if that specific value is in your database. Databases are optimised for such a request. And if there is a lot of data in your database, your approach would need a lot of time to load everything into memory (which can easily result in a memoryError).

So I guess you store your values in a column called 'bar':

```
inputvalue = input("Input= ")
cur = connection.cursor()
query = """ SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE bar = inputvalue """

cur.execute(query)
row_count = cur.rowcount
if row_count > 0:
    print(inputvalue)
else:
    print("Data Does Not Exist")
```

And for you to understand why your approach is not working as expected: With `for x in result:` you loop through every row in your table, and for each row, you check if inputvalue is in there.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, your code is working!. And thank you for pointing out my mistake